# How can I specify the language to be used by Tesseract when using OCRFeeder

Tags: ocr

I'm using the OCR-utility of *OCRFeeder*. OCRFeeder is using the *tesseract*-engine. I have installed the several language-packs needed for tesseract. How can I set the language such that tesseract will use the right language-file for converting the scanned document into text?

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup the engine command line on OCR Feeder settings. It should look like:

```
-l lang_id $IMAGE $FILE; cat $FILE.txt
```

Where lang_id is the id as shown on the correspondin language package name.

Comment: Thank you, João. The language-id must however be specified as the last argument. eg. $IMAGE $FILE -l lang-id; cat $FILE.txt

Comment: I added now several ocr-engines into OCR-Feeder. Goto Tools, OCR-Engines and a a new ocr-engine: I keep using the tesseract-engine, but I specified a new name for each entry made with a specific language-id. So for each language I have now a specific ocr-egine that can be selected by OCR-Feeder (Thanks to João Pinto for the hint)

Comment: The language-tags can be found in synaptic for the tesseract-packages. (spa = spanish, fra = french, deu = german, nld = dutch; ita = italian, por = portugese). eg. for scanning a french text, my Tesseract-French engine has the following command-line: $IMAGE $FILE -l fra; cat $FILE.txt